# PasteSpecial no longer working when going from 2010 to Office 365

Tags: excel, vba, office365

My macro works perfectly on all installed PCs in Excel 2010, but the ones I installed that have Excel 365 give me errors and/or just stop running unexpectedly (I have no error handling... Macro just stops and reopens the file as "Autorecover", without any error box/Debug option). The error occurs on this line (2nd line)

```
Sheet1.range(Sheet1.Cells(row1, col1), Sheet1.Cells(LastRow, col1)).Copy
Sheet2.Cells(row2, "K").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

I get `Error '1004': That command cannot be used on multiple selections.` And sometimes it just exits, without any prompt. 
I've checked and both of my sheets are defined, so are the variables for rows & columns. This is no issue whatsoever on 2010, so I don't think the rest of my code is wrong. Any suggestions? I've read no issues regarding this particular error. Thanks!

Comment: remove the `()` from around `xlPasteValues`

Comment: Woooow. Thank you, that did it. Posted my own answer to mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

`(xlPasteValues)`

to

`xlPasteValues`

Did the trick. Hopefully this  helps someone else who is breaking their head, trying to find  an option in Tools >References that will make the Macro compatible!